# tkinter uses single function callback with arguments to chose what to do

Tags: python, tkinter, button

I've written a code that execute a function in loop while a button is hold and stop the execution when the button is released. See below.

```
class SampleApp(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):

        tk.Tk.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        
        self.sch_plus_button = tk.Button(self, text="S+", command=self.sch_plus_callback)
        self.sch_plus_button.pack()
        self.sch_plus_button.bind('<Button-1>', self.sch_plus_callback)
        self.sch_plus_button.bind('<ButtonRelease-1>', self.button_stop_callback)

    def button_stop_callback(self, event):
        self.after_cancel(repeat)

    def sch_plus_callback(self, *args):
        global repeat
        try:
            # TODO find right time to send data to keep RELE ON
            repeat = self.after(200, self.sch_plus_callback, args[0])
        except IndexError:
            pass
        self.ser.write(b'\x02\x56\x81\x80\x80\x80\x80\x80\x39\x35\x04')
```

Now, as soon as the `sch_plus_callback` function basically do always the same stuff, indipendently by the command I'm gonna press, and the only thing that changes is the string in `ser.write` (which have to change accoridngly to the button I'm pushing) I would like to know if there's a way to send an argument like `self.sch_plus_button.bind('<Button-1>', self.sch_plus_callback("button_1"))` and then get the argument inside my `sch_plus_callback` like

```
def sch_plus_callback(self, *args):
            global repeat
            try:
                # TODO find right time to send data to keep RELE ON
                repeat = self.after(200, self.sch_plus_callback(args[0]), args[1])
            except IndexError:
                pass
            self.ser.write(string_to_send(args[0]))
```

I've tried the code below but, because how my code is written, it triggers `RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded` so I've no idea on how workaround the issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A solution I found has been

```
        self.sch_plus_button = tk.Button(self, text="S+", command=lambda: self.sch_plus_callback('sch_plus'))
        self.sch_plus_button.pack()
        self.sch_plus_button.bind('<Button-1>', lambda event: self.sch_plus_callback('sch_plus', event))
        self.sch_plus_button.bind('<ButtonRelease-1>', self.button_stop_callback)

    def button_stop_callback(self, event):
        self.after_cancel(repeat)

    def sch_plus_callback(self, *args):
        global repeat
        logging.info("args are " + str(args))

        try:
            repeat = self.after(300, self.sch_plus_callback, args[0], args[1])
        except IndexError:
            pass
```

Where `args[0]` is the argument that indicates the button pressed and `args[1]` the event to hendle